# Include OpenCV's extra modules with pip install

Tags: python, opencv

Is it possible to include OpenCV's extra modules with a pip install of opencv-python ? I read the pypi page and it doesn't contain any information regarding it currently.

If not, would the best possible option be to uninstall the pip package and brew install it with a flag?

Answer (score 0):

When building opencv from source you have to compile the **contrib** package separately and then flag cmake to the contrib package.

Assuming that, and this line:

> At the same time it allows anyone to build a custom version of OpenCV
>   for any Python version: just fork this repo and modify the build files
>   and scripts to fit your needs

from pypi opencv [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), you probably **would have to fork and modify the scripts to fit extra pacakges**.